# xpath with node(), how to express `node()[.//x]` condition?

Tags: xpath

I have a XPath that must match text and tags, except the tag `<aa>`; so,

`./node()[name()!='aa']`

is the correct xpath.
But it is insufficient for cases where tag aa is into the node, I need something like,

`./node()[name()!='aa' and not(.//aa)]`

but this xpath **not works (!)**.

---

### NOTE

I used
`./*[not(self::aa or .//aa)] | ./text()`
but it lost the original sequence order of the nodes. This problem is more evident when working with XSLT, example:

```
     <xsl:for-each select="./*[not(self::aa or .//aa)] | ./text()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     <xsl:for-each>
```

not works as expected (the order of nodes is not  ensured).   When using `./node()` the order is always correct.

PS: with XSLT we have a solution using all the explained xpaths,

```
 <xsl:for-each select="./node()[name()!='aa']">
        <xsl:if test="not(.//aa)"><xsl:copy-of select="."/><xsl:if>
 <xsl:for-each>
```

but the ideal/simplest one not works with the same result (when processing big and complex inputs),

```
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::aa or .//aa)] | ./text()"/>
```

Comment: The second expression looks good. How does it fail exactly?

Comment: I edited, adding an XSLT example.

Comment: Strange, XSLT should always process node-sets in document order. Which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Hum.. Thanks, well, I am using [XMLlib2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), with PHP, for both [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) and [XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php)... Ok, my next "homework": get an concrete example, simplify and post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm imagining your file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <aa/>
  <b>
    <aa/>
  </b>
  <c>
    <b>
      <aa/>
    </b>
  </c>
  <d/>
  <e>
    <b/>
  </e>
</root>
```

Then the expression

```
//node()[not(descendant-or-self::aa)]
```

returns all nodes (including the whitespace text nodes) that are not themselves an `<aa>` element or have an `<aa>` descendant.  Children of `<aa>` are matched as well.

You'll probably want to do something like

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(descendant-or-self::aa)]"/>
```

Comment: YES, it is XPath-v1 and works fine!  ... Well, now that my software is working and is optimized, a curiosity.  I not understand WHY `not(descendant-or-self::aa)` works and `not(self::aa or .//aa)` not works, you have an theoretical explanation for this syntatic decision of the xpath language?

Comment: I don't see a difference in meaning. On my test document, both expressions return the same nodes.

Comment: Ops, sorry, re-writing, `"./node()[name()!='aa' and not(.//aa)]"` vs `"./node()[not(descendant-or-self::aa)]"` ... Both returns the same result? (if return I must delete the question?)